# How can I configure RAID1 for /boot and OS installation, desktop 20.04.1?

Tags: grub2, 20.04, raid, bootloader, mirrors

Can someone please help?

I have a newly installed Ubuntu Desktop 20.04.1 installation on a laptop having dual internal disks. I freshly installed the OS following instructions to create an (almost) full disk encryption as follows:

```
sda                      8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk  
├─sda1                   8:1    0   768M  0 part  
│ └─LUKS_BOOT          253:3    0   766M  0 crypt /boot
├─sda2                   8:2    0     2M  0 part  
├─sda3                   8:3    0   128M  0 part  /boot/efi
└─sda5                   8:5    0 464.9G  0 part  
  └─sda5_crypt         253:0    0 464.9G  0 crypt 
    ├─ubuntu--vg-swap_1
    │                  253:1    0     4G  0 lvm   [SWAP]
    └─ubuntu--vg-root  253:2    0 368.7G  0 lvm   /
sdb                      8:16   0   477G  0 disk
```

My goal is a dual disk boot environment with RAID1 on boot and the OS (sda1 and sda5) so if a disk fails I can boot and run from the other disk. I have searched a lot on this and I can only seem to come across information for non-OS mirrors or installing Ubuntu server. Maybe some can please point me to a published instruction. Thanks!